# How to delete unsuitable rows from .CSV file and save that file again by using C#?

Tags: c#, csv, save, rows

I want to select a .csv file by using browse button and pressing Index button then delete some unsuitable rows from .csv file and save it.please help me to do this.it is a great help me to solve my problem.

This is my .csv file like bellow.

```
Date,Step Time, Mode Duration (secs),Duration (in Hrs),Schedule,Index,Mode

30/03/2017 23:31:35,42824.98027,0,180,0,1,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:36,42824.98028,0.00001,180,0,1,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:38,42824.9803,0.00002,180,1,2,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:39,42824.98031,0.00001,180,1,1,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:41,42824.98034,0.00002,180,1,1,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:41,42824.98034,0,180,2,2,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:43,42824.98036,0.00002,180,2,1,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:45,42824.98038,0.00002,180,2,1,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:45,42824.98038,0,180,3,2,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:47,42824.98041,0.00002,180,3,1,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:49,42824.98043,0.00002,180,3,1,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:49,42824.98043,0,180,4,2,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:51,42824.98045,0.00002,180,4,1,TRUE
30/03/2017 23:31:53,42824.98047,0.00002,180,4,1,TRUE
```

NOTE:
In this .csv file I want to delete the rows by considering following conditions.

Mode Duration (secs)=0 and Index=2

my code is like below,but not complete.

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
  private void btnIndex_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Graph> ObservingData = new List<Graph>(); // List to store all 

            // Loops through each lines in the CSV
            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(tbOutputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
            {

                string[] CsvLine = line.Split(',');
                Graph Instance1 = new Graph();

                Instance1.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(CsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
                Instance1.StepTime = double.Parse(CsvLine[1]);
                Instance1.ModeDuration = double.Parse(CsvLine[2]);
                Instance1.Duration = int.Parse(CsvLine[3]);
                Instance1.ScheduleStep = int.Parse(CsvLine[4]);
                Instance1.Index = int.Parse(CsvLine[5]);
                Instance1.Mode = (CsvLine[6] == "TRUE" ? true : false);

                if (Instance1.ModeDuration == 0 && Instance1.Index == 2) 
                {
                    continue;
                    //write code

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already? What is your *concrete* problem? Right now your "question" is in fact "do my job, please" request, nothing more.

Comment: read all text, convert to object array, filter, write back, which is difficult for you?

Comment: Just to be clear... Do you need someone to actually write the whole thing? Have you done anything?

Comment: @LeiYang I added my code here.I want to how to select that row from .csv file and save the updated .csv file.please help me to do this.I'm newer to this language.

Comment: there are some existing libraries to read csv, such as in [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=csv)

Comment: @AndyKorneyev ,i added code that I did yet,but not complete it.I want ,how to select  row by considering conditions(ModeDuration = 0 & Index == 2) from .csv file and want to delete that rows and save the updated .csv file.please help me to do this.

Comment: @FrancescoMilani. ,I added code that I did yet,but not complete it.I want ,how to select row by considering conditions(ModeDuration = 0 & Index = 2) from .csv file and want to delete that rows and save the updated .csv file.please help me to do this. I am a newer to this language.

Comment: @LeiYang.ok I will check that link now.thank you sir.

Comment: For starters... I suggest you solve one problem at a time "divide et impera". Assuming you're ok with your own parser, one way could be: build your own RowClass with the properties you need. Write a parsing method from "string" to RowClass so you can have a List<RowClass> containing all the lines.. Then you can use LINQ like this:
"foreach (RowClass row in allRows.Where(r => r.ModeDuration == 0 && r.Index == 2) { .. }"

Comment: @FrancescoMilani thank you sir,I will try that.but i'm a newer to this language.So if you can please help me further.thank you very much sir.

Comment: @FrancescoMilani,Sir If you can please edit my code.It is great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your problem is writing the file...

```
private void btnIndex_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Graph> ObservingData = new List<Graph>(); // List to store all 

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("your new file.csv"))
    {
        // Loops through each lines in the CSV
        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(tbOutputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
        {

            string[] CsvLine = line.Split(',');
            Graph Instance1 = new Graph();

            Instance1.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(CsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Instance1.StepTime = double.Parse(CsvLine[1]);
            Instance1.ModeDuration = double.Parse(CsvLine[2]);
            Instance1.Duration = int.Parse(CsvLine[3]);
            Instance1.ScheduleStep = int.Parse(CsvLine[4]);
            Instance1.Index = int.Parse(CsvLine[5]);
            Instance1.Mode = (CsvLine[6] == "TRUE" ? true : false);

            if (Instance1.ModeDuration != 0 || Instance1.Index != 2)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(line);

            }
        }

        sw.Close();
    }


}
```

Please, you should consider reading [help ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

I'm guessing that nobody will help you if you can't be specific

Comment: thank you very much for your help sir,I can understand I am wrong.But I don't have ask from anyone to clarify my problem.that's why I ask from you.I am a newer to this language.thank you again

Comment: This code is working fine.but name of header columns are not in new .csv file.can you explain this sir.I remove skip(1) keyword from code.then error message is coming"An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format." .So can you explain about that.please give me a solution for this.

Comment: Ok sir,I did it.Thank you for your help very much.